# Compare multi-trigger's binding with value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, multidatatrigger

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition>
            <Condition.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanOr}">
                    <Binding Path="Property Value =5"/>
                    <Binding Path="Property Value =10"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Condition.Binding>
        </Condition>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
```

///Do something here based on condition....

The code means when Value eqauls 5 or 20 ===> Do something.

I followed [this](http://www.charlierobbins.com/articles/2009/03/16/wpf-tips-how-to-use-a-multitrigger-with-an-or-condition/) one for multi-triggers

But `"Binding Path="Property Value =5""` this line obviously is wrong.

What should I write here in order to compare Value is 5 or not
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need another converter to see if one value is equal to whatever value you're comparing against

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanOr}">
    <Binding Path="Value" ConverterParameter="5" Converter="{StaticResource IsValueEqualParameterConverter}" />
    <Binding Path="Value" ConverterParameter="10" Converter="{StaticResource IsValueEqualParameterConverter}" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Another option is to use `DataTriggers`

```
<Style>
    <Setter Property="SomeProperty" Value="FalseValue" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="5">
            <Setter Property="SomeProperty" Value="TrueValue" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="10">
            <Setter Property="SomeProperty" Value="TrueValue" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have more than one condition you do not need a `MultiDataTrigger`.

If you want to compare to a value you could use a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) where the `Binding.ConverterParameter` is set to said value. The converter would just compare the value and parameter (possibly with parsing applied to the parameter if it is not passed as an `int`)

Do not put anything besides the property path into the `Path` of course. The converter should directly return `true` or `false` as this presumably is expected by the `MultiBinding.Converter`.

Comment: actually I have lot of to compare. I want to trigger the action when value from 0 ~ 20 actually. Can you give me some code example how to do this? thanks.

Comment: @AndersLind: I will not, if need an example for a converter look at the reference i linked. And comparing values and parsing strings hardly needs an example either, if it does you might want to look at the `Parse` and `TryParse` methods which can be found on about every primitive type.